# Java Generics declaration

Tags: java, generics, types

i have these classes

```
class SuperParent {
        @Override
        public String toString() {

            return "SuperParent";
        }
    }

    class A extends SuperParent {

        @Override
        public String toString() {

            return "A";
        }
    }

    class B extends SuperParent {

        @Override
        public String toString() {

            return "B";
        }

    }
```

and i want to have a `List` of ArrayLists , so i can add to ArrayList of B's and A's 
i tried

```
List<ArrayList<?extends SuperParent>> mList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<SuperParent>>();
```

but does not compile

when i tried this,

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<SuperParent>> mList = new ArrayList<SuperParent>>();
```

it compiles but i cant add `ArrayList`s of `A`s or `ArrayList`s `B`s

i understand java types and inheritance too  but when it comes to Generics i miss with it .
Any reference or a declaration would help me .

Comment: If this code is taken verbatim, then there are some typos which would prevent compilation.

Comment: There are few typos in your code.

Comment: Typo = typing mistake. For instance, you have ArrayList<ArrayList<SupperParent>> mList

Comment: There's also 'exnteds' instead of `extends`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would declare a list of lists where the elements of outer list can be a list of A or list of B:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends SuperParent>> lists = 
    new ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends SuperParent>>();
lists.add(new ArrayList<A>(Arrays.asList(new A(), new A())));
lists.add(new ArrayList<B>(Arrays.asList(new B(), new B())));
```

Generally, it is recommended to use interface types than concrete types when declaring or accepting as method parameters. That way, the above snippet would look like below:

```
List<List<? extends SuperParent>> lists = 
    new ArrayList<List<? extends SuperParent>>();
lists.add(Arrays.asList(new A(), new A()));
lists.add(Arrays.asList(new B(), new B()));
```

Comment: extensive FAQ on generics: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you tried, but this works for me:

```
public class SuperParent
{

@Test
public void testThatAddThowsNoExceptions()
{
    List<ArrayList<? extends SuperParent>> mList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<? extends SuperParent>>();
    ArrayList<SuperParent> firstList = new ArrayList<SuperParent>();
    firstList.add(new SuperParent());
    firstList.add(new A());
    firstList.add(new B());
    mList.add(firstList);
}

public String toString()
{

    return "SuperParent";
}

class A extends SuperParent
{

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {

        return "A";
    }
}

class B extends SuperParent
{

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {

        return "B";
    }

}

}
```